# Set category's canonical URL on a custom route

Tags: plugin-seomatic

Global category content canonical URL pattern seems to set og:url, but not the canonical one. I've tried replacing `@web` with the address proper without any change. I suspect I've misconfigured something.

The category group's URL pattern is: `product-categories/{slug}`,
and it's canonical URL in content SEO is: `@web/products/{category.slug}`.
A custom route loads the template: `products/{tag}`.
Which does a: `seomatic.helper.loadMetadataForUri(category.uri)`.

However,

In a category's SEO preview the canonical URL is still `product-categories/{slug}`.
While in the header of a `product/{category}` page the canonical URL link isn't present.

Adding a link with `seomatic.link.create({"rel": "canonical","href": canonicalUrl,})` works like a charm.

Comment: What do you have the Canonical URL set to in Content SEO for your Category Group?

Comment: That's that `@web/products/{category.slug}`.

Comment: Old question, I know, but still. Have you tried using `{% do seomatic.meta.canonicalUrl( seomatic.helper.safeCanonicalUrl() ) %}`